# Bulk Load Data Jobs hanging in Queue

Tags: data-loader, bulk

I am working with the bulk load API v52. I have successfully created a job and uploaded a single record CSV to test via rest. I login to the console and I see the job in progress in the monitor bulk data load jobs. This is the only thig running, and this is a sandbox environment so there is nothing else running here. My quota is completely unused:

```
` Your organization has processed 0 batches in the last 24 hours. Your organization can process 15,000 batches in a 24-hour period.
Resource used in the last 24 hours:
CPU: 210 milliseconds
IO: 0 bytes
Disk: 0 bytes
`
```

Concurrency mode is set to parallel, and this is an update job. Ideally, I would like to be able to push it out of queue so I can test rapidly.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? My job also seems to be stuck in "Queued" status

Answer (score 1):

Found out I was missing a step:

1. Create Job
2. Upload Data
3. **Update Job State to "UploadComplete"**

Basically, you have to tell the job you are done uploading data.

Then the job will start.

Example URI

```
/services/data/v55.0/jobs/ingest/jobId/
```

Example PATCH request

```
curl https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/jobs/ingest/7505fEXAMPLE4C2AAM/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer 00DE0X0A0M0PeLE!AQcAQH0dMHEXAMPLEzmpkb58urFRkgeBGsxL_QJWwYMfAbUeeG7c1EXAMPLEDUkWe6H34r1AAwOR8B8fLEz6nEXAMPLE' -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1" --data-raw '{ "state" : "UploadComplete" }' -X PATCH
```

[See more in official docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/walkthrough_upload_data.htm)

Comment: Literally used
curl https://MYDOMAIN.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/jobs/ingest/7507Z00000IUBlFQAX/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKENHERE' -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1" --data-raw '{ "state" : "UploadComplete" }' -X PATCH
but got 
[ {
  "errorCode" : "BULK_API_ERROR",
  "message" : "Cannot specify query parameters on this resource"
} ]
Cannot find much on this error unfortunately :(